# static library used in lower version gcc

Tags: c++, c, gcc, static-libraries

I have encountered a strange problem.

(1)I build a module to a static library xxx.a via gcc (version 2.96-110) firstly. And some code in xxx.a is like :

```
const char * const str = “hello world”
void fun()
{
printf(“%s”, str);
return;
}
```

(2)Then I link xxx.a with my program EXE via gcc(version 2.96-98). In EXE , API fun() is invoked.

(3)When I run EXE, the output is “llo world”, not “hello world”. It is so strange.

Is is caused by the difference of gcc version?

Comment: Looks like an ABI difference. Maybe some kind of stack smashing protection that's enabled on the later version? Try disabling stack protection.

Comment: Maybe, but it could also be because of bugs in you **ancient** version of GCC. You do know it's up to version 4.8?

Comment: GCC 2.96? Are you a time traveller from the 1990s?

Comment: Our product travels form 1990s ^_^

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Note that [there was never any official GCC 2.96 release](http://gcc.gnu.org/gcc-2.96.html):

> It has come to our attention that some GNU/Linux distributions are currently shipping with ``GCC 2.96''.
>
> We would like to point out that GCC 2.96 is not a formal GCC release nor will there ever be such a release. Rather, GCC 2.96 has been the code-name for our development branch that will eventually become GCC 3.0.

[GCC 3.0](http://gcc.gnu.org/gcc-3.0/) was a major effort that involved an ABI change from [GCC 2.95](http://gcc.gnu.org/gcc-2.95/). Since "GCC 2.96" was based on snapshots of GCC 3.0 development, the ABI was probably in flux, and you are suffering the side-effect of using a development snapshot as a production compiler.

Comment: +1, although I'm guessing that "hello world" is not production code ;)

Comment: Thanks for your answers. It is valuable for me.

Answer (score 1):

It has always been the case that you cannot use an older G++ to link than you used to compile any object or library, so what you're doing is unlikely to work with any two GCC versions, especially not the unofficial, unstable 2.96 series.

Join us in 2013 and use at least GCC 4.4

Answer (score 0):

It looks like a stack corruption, may be caused by the unofficial GCC version.If you have the source code, why not compile the library using newest GCC?